# Getting the Order of Taskbar Buttons

Tags: c++, windows

I'd like to be able to get a list of the buttons in the taskbar in the order that they appear to the user. The reason for this is because I'd like to position windows on the screen based on the order they appear in the taskbar.

I'm able to get the handle of the taskbar using

```
HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
HWND hTray    = FindWindowEx( hDesktop, 0, "Shell_TrayWnd" , 0);
HWND hReBar   = FindWindowEx( hTray   , 0, "ReBarWindow32" , 0);
HWND hTask    = FindWindowEx( hReBar  , 0, "MSTaskSwWClass", 0);
```

but I can't find anything that lets me interate through the buttons on the taskbar.

I feel it may have something to do with `SendMessage()` and `TB_GETBUTTONINFO`, but even then I can't understand how I could interate through all the existing buttons.

Comment: Haha I wish I knew how to change the order of buttons in the taskbar!

Comment: I'm not trying to change the order; I just want to access what the current order is.